# visual studio 2015 stuck when building, killing find.exe (three times) completes the build process

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, freeze

Visual studio 2015 gets stuck when I am building a rather complex solution...

I discovered that building starts "find.exe" and killing "find.exe" lets the build complete.

I have another project of similar complexity that builds fine without me needing to kill anything.

The project is .Net4.0 full framework, most of the projects are c#

I don't really see any hints as to why it is hanging, and from the build output in the console it seems it gets stuck at different places each time.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem...

in some 'pre-build' scripts, I invoked a 'replaceString.bat' batch file, from commandline, and vs2010/2012... it worked fine. But in 2015, as mentioned, it stalled with the find.exe running...
The content of the bad batch file was this:

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::BatchSubstitude - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
:$changed 20100115
:$source http://www.dostips.com
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

I have now replaced it with a .net exe file and it works